# Correct @font-face { } for MATHJAX 2.7.1 to avoid a "Ensure text remains visible during Webfont load" error

Tags: html, css, mathjax

I am using Mathjax 2.7.1 on my blogger website. It is working perfectly fine for displaying the equations. But when I am checking the performance of my webpage, I am getting errors in Google PageSpeed Insights.

The following URLs are causing a **"Ensure text remains visible during Webfont load"** error:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Main-Regular.woff?V=2.7.1

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Math-Italic.woff?V=2.7.1

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Size1-Regular.woff?V=2.7.1

How can I remove this error? **What is the correct @font-face{ } for Mathjax 2.7.1 ?**

I am using the following script to enable the features in my website:

```js
<script async='async' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js' type='text/javascript'>
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js","TeX/AMSmath.js","TeX/AMSsymbols.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
        displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
    },
    "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `font-display: swap;` in your CSS. This prevents blocking during render and text will remain visible.

```
* {
    font-display: swap;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display

Comment: The target is not achieved just by adding this line in CSS. I have used another font name "Fontawesome". For this font I have used the CSS block :

@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-weight: normal;
    font-display: swap;
  font-style: normal;
  src:  url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0") format("woff2");
}

Comment: So, a proper @font-face{} block is needed for mathjax.